# Memory Internal and integer as outpout?

Tags: java, android, android-memory

I would like to know the Total Internal Memory and write it in a Preference so I wrote this code:

```
 File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
 StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
 long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
 long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
 long Size = totalBlocks * blockSize/1073741824;

 memory = (Preference) this.findPreference("free");
 memory.setSummary(Long.toString(Size)+" GB");
```

1073741824 corresponds to 1024*1024*1024 for obtaining teh GigaByte. Now, the problem is, why the result is an integer? For example, in the Preference is written "5" but if I do the calculation and divide the variable size for 1024/1024 i get 5393 and which is divided again by 1024 is 5,26, but since then I receive only 5 as outpout? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`long` variables can only hold long integers. You have to use a floating point type instead. For example:

```
double size = totalBlocks * blockSize / 1073741824d;
```

Another point to make sure is that at least one of the operands in your calculation is also a floating point type (see the `d` suffix to the constant). Otherwise Java will calculate an integer value and assign it to the double variable.

Furthermore, by convention, your variables should not start with a capital letter. This style is reserved for type names.

Comment: Thanks! It Works but now i see a number as 13,328445434570313How can I get only the first decimal place?

Comment: One possibility to round to the first decimal place: `size = Math.round(size * 10) / 10d` ([via](http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/1797912))

Answer (score -1):

Do the division declaring the GB long as a float

```
long Size = totalBlocks * blockSize/1073741824f;
```

Comment: Unless you change the type of `Size` from `long` to `float` or `double`, it's still going to end up as `5`.

Comment: Missed that you declared the size as a long.  Use a double or float to store the result.  See other answer.  :)